# sub dataframe using pandas in dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning

I had this titanic_excel dataframe

[image: titanic_frame]

I tried the below code:

```
row_index=titanic_excel[["Name","Age","Sex"]]
row_index
```

what I got is:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

if the question you are trying to solve is the one in the image, then you could simply use this code to print those values you need:

```py
titanic_excel.iloc[10:26, 3:6]
```

This code extracts the rows with indices from 10 (included) to 26 (excluded) and the columns with indices from 3 (included) to 6 (excluded) meaning that in practice you'll get the rows with indices from 10 to 25 and the columns from 3 to 5 as requested.

Instead, if you want to extract the columns by their name, and still fetching the rows from 10 to 25 you can use this command:

```py
titanic_excel[['Name', 'Sex', 'Age']][10:26]
```

Again, here you are extracting those columns whose name is in the list `['Name', 'Sex', 'Age']` and those rows from index 10 (included) to 26 (excluded).

TL;DR
Here some further readings on the topic:

[iloc documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html)

[dataframe indexing and slicing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html)